# Why is HttpGet required only for some actions?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Let me sketch the situation first:

I have a basic controller which looks like this:

```
public class SearchRequestController : ApiController
{
    public IEnumerable<ObjectA> GetAllRequests() {...}
    {}
    public IEnumerable<ObjectA> GetLatestRequest() {...}
    {}
}
```

Using the following routing

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

I can easly use the functions as follows

```
 Http://myServer/myvirtualdirectory/api/SearchRequest/GetAllRequests
 Http://myServer/myvirtualdirectory/api/SearchRequest/GetLatestRequest
```

Now i wanted to add the following controller

```
 public class UserController : ApiController
 {
    public IEnumerable<UserObject> SearchUsersByInput() {...}
 }
```

But the following GET doesn't work

```
 Http://myServer/myvirtualdirectory/api/User/SearchUsersByInput

 I'm getting a 405: {"Message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'."}
```

It works however when I change my function as follows:

```
 public class UserController : ApiController
 {
  [HttpGet]
  public IEnumerable<UserObject> SearchUsersByInput() {...}
 }
```

**Question:**
Could someone explain the origin of this behavior? Have I done something wrong or is there something wrong with my routing?

Comment: It just didn't get picked up because you didn't specify the attribute nor followed naming conventions.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Thnx for the reply. The attribute you're reffering to is `[HttpGet]` correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please refer to the post [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api)

You will see that you can use naming convention (which is why the methods with Get in the name work), or you can explicitly specify the HTTP method for an action by decorating the action with the correct HTTP attribute.

Comment: Indeed remarkable. Changing the functionname from `Search`UsersByInput()  to `Get`UsersByInput() did solve it for me.

Comment: Ugh. Magical naming conventions in WebAPI do my head in.

Answer (score 1):

This is default behaviour of the web-services in asp.net - they aren't supporting the `GET` method without explicit specifying that they should.

So simply use the [`[HttpGetAttribute]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.httpgetattribute.aspx) for the methods needs to support the `GET` via http:

> Represents an attribute that is used to restrict an action method so that the method handles only HTTP GET requests.

Comment: Thnx for the information. Some further reading about the `[HttpGetAttribute]` did give me offer my lots of desirable information about routing.